# Place an object on top of border, aligned to the center

Tags: html, css

I basically want something like this:

[image]

The oval is a button called specific, its size depends on the text. The border belongs to a div called player. The button should always align to the center of the top border no matter what the sizes they are. Thanks.

```
#specific
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff; 
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.player
{
  width: 560px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  <?php echo $border.$border_color[0] ?>;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML code, if it is relevant:

```
<input type="button" id="specific" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick='window.open("<?php echo $specific; ?>")'>

<div class="player">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $url;?>"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code also. how can we find it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put #specific inside the player div and position it absolutely.

Then it can be managed into place using position values and a transform.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#specific
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff; 
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lightblue;
  border:inherit;
}
.player
{
  width: 560px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em;
  border-style: solid;
 border-color:blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div id="specific">Specific</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the best because I have other text and stuff before and after the border, so z-index will be a bad idea. And  this still works if font size is changed (No readjustment needed).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add `position: relative` to `.player`, and wrap your button with a div (let's call it `.buttonWrap`), which has the following css attached:

```
.buttonWrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px; /* the number of pixels here should be calculated like (buttonHeight / 2) */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#specific
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff; 
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.player
{
  width: 560px;
  padding: 20px;
 margin: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  <?php echo $border.$border_color[0] ?>;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
}
.button{
  width: 560px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
 <input type="button" id="specific" value="Play" onclick='window.open("<?php echo $specific; ?>")'>
</div>
<div class="player">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $url;?>"></script>
</div>
```

here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hqqykjgL/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-lg {
  border: 4px solid rgba(50, 150, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

button.container-sm {
  background-color: rgba(100, 175, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-lg">
  <button class="container-sm"></button>
</div>
```